# Problems with Magento extension installation

Tags: php, magento

I have installed a Magento extension provided here: [multistore extension](https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-currency-auto-switcher.html)

Here are the steps followed during the installation:

```
uploaded unzip folders in magento respective subfolders
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

**All the configurations and enabled the extension also.**

After running the aforementioned commands, the design of the site gets disturbed and all the CSS and JS files are not loaded/not found.

What could be the possible issue behind the broken design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things could be wrong here.

You should not be using sudo, all your generated files and assets are now going to be owned by root.

Are you deploying a none standard locale?

try deploying content with specific locale(s):

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_US -f
```

What deployment mode are you in? Production / Developer?

Comment: Worked. I'll let you know if more problems come up.

Comment: On a shared hosting - copied extension files in app/code folder and then followed the steps in option 2 here [How to install Magento extension manually](https://marketplace.magento.com/media/catalog/product/pozzito-pozzito-module-livechat-100-0-2-ce/user_guides.pdf). It throws an error when followed 8th step. Any ideas? I guess we somehow need to disable the compiler and then activate again.

Comment: If you have done step 8 u should also compile and deploy static content as in your list above

Comment: This is on a shared hosting with a cPanel - no SSH access. Can we do it there?